# PHP script halts with no errors when using openssl

Tags: php, apache, openssl

The following script halts at the `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` call with no errors. It was doing this originally with a `openssl_decrypt()` call.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo extension_loaded('openssl') . '<br>';

print_r(openssl_get_cipher_methods());

echo '<br>end';
```

Returns:

```
1
```

Could this be a problem with the hosting service? The script output says that the module is loaded and phpinfo() returns this:

```
openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Version     OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips 26 Jan 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

FIPS builds of openSSL are a bit special. Amongst other things they don't seem to have `openssl_get_cipher_methods`. FIPS builds are meant for systems that have to comply with strict rules about encryption where the code must be minimalistic so that is stays provably the same.

https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_Build_Guidelines

See also lines 47-53 here: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/src/RuntimeTests.php